# how do I get class name from jobject in jvmti

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I am trying to get the class name from jobject in jvmti, I tried get

```
(*jvmti)->GetClassSignature(jvmti, object_klass, &signature, &generic);
```

for code like this

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    names.add("foo");
    names.add("bar");
    System.out.println(names);
}
```

I am tracking all allocation of objects in jvmti, I don't get `java.util.HashSet` in this hook

I get bunch of

```
Ljava/lang/String;     Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/io/Serializable;Ljava/lang/Comparable<Ljava/lang/String;>;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;
Ljava/lang/reflect/Method; (null)
```

and some other classes, but I don't see `new  HashSet<>` initialization

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are trying [VMObjectAlloc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#VMObjectAlloc) JVMTI notification. This notification is not sent for allocations made in Java code. This behaviour is described in JVMTI specification:

> Sent when ... the allocation is not detectable by other intrumentation mechanisms. Generally object allocation should be detected by instrumenting the
>   bytecodes of allocating methods.
>
> ...
>
> Cases where this event would not be generated:
>
> - Allocation due to bytecodes - for example, the new and newarray VM instructions
> - Allocation due to JNI function calls - for example, AllocObject
> - Allocations during VM initialization
> - VM internal objects

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924300/how-to-intercept-object-creation-in-java-lower-than-user-class-level/35927613#35927613) explains how to track object allocations in Java.